# Laravel - Load a JSON file from /resources folder for API

Tags: php, json, laravel, storage

Within a Laravel project, I have an API that is powered by a flat JSON file. I'd like to use the JSON file where it currently resides, which is inside the /resources/modules/ folder in project. Problem is I'm having trouble targeting this location with the Storage:: method. Currently I have the file located in `storage/app/public`, which works fine with the code below, but ideally I'd reference the `/resources/modules/` file.

```
    $this->json_path = Storage::disk('public')->get('file.json');
    $this->config_decoded = json_decode($this->json_path, true);
```

How do I do this using the Storage:: method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you've updated your `public` disk to point to the `resources/modules` directory, this is to be expected. By default, the `public` disk points to your `storage/app/public` directory.

You can either set up a new disk in your `config/filesystems.php` file by adding the something like the following to the `disks` array:

```
'modules' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => resource_path('modules'),
    'throw' => false,
],
```

Then your code would be:

```
$this->json_path = Storage::disk('modules')->get('file.json');
$this->config_decoded = json_decode($this->json_path, true);
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the `File` facade instead:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

$this->json_path = File::get(resource_path('modules/bob.json'))
```